# Reading a file into a javascript array

Tags: javascript, webview

I'm aware JS isn't a server side script, but I'm building a mobile app, and I'm going to use the web view controller on android and would like the ability to be able to read a file into an array using JS. Is there anyway of doing this?

Thanks

Comment: JS is server-side script.  http://nodejs.org

Comment: Is it a local file (on device) or a file on server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [HTML5 FileReader API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/FileReader). With it you can read the file as:

```
void readAsArrayBuffer(in Blob blob); //Requires Gecko 7.0
void readAsBinaryString(in Blob blob);
void readAsDataURL(in Blob file);
void readAsText(in Blob blob, [optional] in DOMString encoding);
```

Here are few [examples](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/).

Comment: Thank you! Didn't realise there was such an option with HTML 5.